# iOS OpenURL queryString not sent

Tags: ios, openurl

I want to share message from iOS app to whatsApp. For this I am using the following code:

```
NSString *strMsg = @"whatsapp://send?text=I%20found%20this.%20Check%20it%20out.Deal_1403803205.6628140%20http://MyiOSApp/register.php?deal_id=978&l_id=198&share=true&customer_id=34&domain=5";
    NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strMsg];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    } else {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"WhatsApp is not installed on your device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

The problem is that the message after the `?` is not sent.

This works: `@"whatsapp://send?text=I%20found%20this.%20Check%20it%20out.Deal_1403803205.6628140%20http://MyiOSApp/register.php`

But this doesn't :

`@"whatsapp://send?text=I%20found%20this.%20Check%20it%20out.Deal_1403803205.6628140%20http://MyiOSApp/register.php?deal_id=978&l_id=198&share=true&customer_id=34&domain=5";`

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode it properly, use -

```
@"whatsapp://send?text=I%20found%20this.%20Check%20it%20out.Deal_1403803205.6628140%20http://MyiOSApp/register.php%3Fdeal_id=978&l_id=198&share=true&customer_id=34&domain=5";
```

"?" character is not encoded, you need to encode that as above.

Comment: Correct, all the special chars need to be encoded, and here in your case its "?"

Comment: If your problem is solved, you can accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as rishi said proper encoding very important.

To encode the message use the following code.

```
- (NSString *)getEncodedMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    CFStringRef encodedMessage = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)message, NULL,
                                                                        (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return CFBridgingRelease(encodedMessage);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7 and above:

```
NSString *escapedString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
```